# Fourier transform of $1/x$, $x>0$

Tags: fourier-analysis

I'm new to Fourier transform. From [Does the Fourier Transform exist for f(t) = 1/t?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033870/does-the-fourier-transform-exist-for-ft-1-t) ,I saw that the Fourier transform of $1/x$ is $\text{sgn}(x)$. Define
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x} &\text{if}\,\,x>0\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
It seems to me that the Fourier transform of $f$ is still $1/x$ (up to a multiple of constant). Am I correct? I just "followed" the same method as in that post.