# Integration of the product of a function and the Heaviside function

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, fourier-transform

while solving a problem in quantum electrodynamics I have to solve the following integral: $$\int_0^t\hat{\pi}(t')\int_{0}^{+\infty} k^2    \Big\{ e^{ik(r-R)} -e^{-ik(r-R)}\Big\}e^{-ick (t-t')}dk \, dt'.$$
As the integral over $k$  is similar to Fourier Transform integrals, it makes sense to write it as
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} k^2  \mathcal{H}(k)    e^{ick(t'-t+\frac{r-R}{c})}dk -\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} k^2 \mathcal{H}(k)  e^{ick(t'-t-\frac{r-R}{c})}dk$$
with $\mathcal{H}(k)$ the Heaviside function. I know that the Fourier Transform of the Heaviside function will have a contribution of the Dirac Delta and another of the Cauchy Principal Value. The first one makes sense to me as it will easily solve the integral over $t'$ evaluating the operator $\hat{\pi}$ in a retarded time. Furthermore, due to the $k^2$ factor I can't find a way to solve this integral.
Notice that it one defines $\xi=c(t'-t-\frac{r-R}{c})$, my problem is reduced to solve the integral $$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} k^2  \mathcal{H}(k)    e^{i\xi  k}dk $$
I hope you can help me to solve it

Comment: Roughly speaking, you want to calculate the inverse Fourier transform of $k^{2}H\left(k\right)$.You can try to calculate the second derivative of the inverse Fourier transform of $H\left(k\right)$ (take a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033870/does-the-fourier-transform-exist-for-ft-1-t)

Comment: PERFECT !!! This is exactly what I need, thank you so much.