# Fourier transform and Limit of complex functions multiplied trigo functions

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

I would like to calculate the Fourier Transform for
$$
\frac{1}{1+x^2}.
$$

By definition
\begin{align}\DeclareMathOperator{atan}{atan}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^2}e^{-i\omega x}dx
&= e^{-i\omega x}\atan(x) + i\omega\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\omega x}\atan(x)dx \\
&= e^{-i\omega x}\atan(x) + i\omega\frac{\atan(x)e^{-i\omega x}}{-i\omega} - i\omega\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^2}e^{-i\omega x}.
\end{align}

Thus
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^2}e^{-i\omega x}dx = \left.\frac{e^{-i\omega x}\atan(x) + i\omega\frac{atan(x)e^{-i\omega x}}{-i\omega}}{1+i\omega}\right |_{-\infty}^{\infty}
$$

and now I'm stuck with how I should carry on.

**Original question :**
How can I calculate the following limit
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\atan(x)e^{-i\omega x}
$$

where $\omega\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Integration by parts isn't working.  You ended up with undetermined terms.  The integral is very suspect.  The integrand does not go to zero at $\infty$.

Comment: Looked up in integral table.  Answer is $\pi e^{-|\omega|}$

Comment: ye @herbsteinberg i just wonder how?

Comment: I got it from Gradshteyn and Ryzhik. (3.723).  They give a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for $\omega=0$ the limit doesn't exist, since $\lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan(x)=\pi/2$ and $$\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-i\omega x}\overset{\omega\neq0}{=}\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{\pm ix}$$ ($\pm$ dependent on the sign of $\omega$) which doesn't exist as $$e^{\pm ix}=\cos(x)\pm i\sin(x)$$ is a oscillating function.

---

Regarding your Edit:

I think you are following a wrong path. Because of the reasons above, you can't do integration by parts. Instead you could try to use
$$\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{x+i}\cdot\frac{1}{x-i}$$
and the formular for the Fourier transform of products. With the substitution $u:=x\pm i$ you just have to calculate the Fourier transform of the function $f(u)=1/u$, which has been described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033870/does-the-fourier-transform-exist-for-ft-1-t).

Comment: Thanks! i actually expanded my question since i felt it wasnt informant enough with the background of where it came from

Comment: is it not $(1+x)(1-x) = x^2 - 1$ ?

Comment: Sry, little typo.

Comment: $e^{ix}=cos(x)+isin(x)$.  You switched the trig functions.

Comment: @herb thanks. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

$\arctan(x)\to \frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi$ and $e^{-i\omega x}$ has no limit, so the product has no limit.

Comment: Thanks! i actually expanded my question since i felt it wasnt informant enough with the background of where it came from